# AdMob ads are transparent, but clickable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob, invisible, adbannerview

So on Unity I have a script that handles the AdMob ads. When I build and test the ad is there and clickable, but it is not **visible**.

I've tried literally everything. Made another ad, tried ads from previous projects that work in those projects, updated the plugin, downloaded new assets, tried different scripts, made sure nothing isn't on top of it... I have no clue what to do next. Below is the script. This currently applies the ad, but it is not visible. You can click it however.

`

```
BannerView bannerView;
string adID = "HERE-IS-MY-AD-ID";
// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    showBannerAd ();
}
private void showBannerAd()
{
    bannerView = new BannerView (adID, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Top);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder ().Build ();
    bannerView.LoadAd (request);
    bannerView.Show ();
}
    public void Show()
{
    bannerView.Show ();
}
    public void Hide()
{
    bannerView.Hide ();
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative solution.You can use Unity Ads(built-in service) instead,and you do not need to install any plugins, which is very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are encountering this problem on Android, your issue might be related to this bug https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/regression-android-banner-ads-are-invisible-but-clickable

I updated to Unity 5.6.1p4 and it fixed my problem.